# After upgrade to 16.04, nothing on secondary display

Tags: boot, upgrade, display

I have an old Thinkpad running Ubuntu 14 all the time since god knows when. It has a broken display but I use it with an external display through a VGA cable. Everything runs ok, it's not a blast anymore but for browsing forums from the workshop in the basement it is enough.

Unfortunately a little devil rode me and I decided to upgrade Ubuntu and the system offered me Ubuntu 16 for upgrade. That process worked just fine, but now I have the problem that I am not able to use the laptop anymore.

At startup lilo shows up on the external monitor, then various messages show up with what is going on, at one point I have a mouse pointer on the external display and then I get nothing. Display is going to sleep due to lack of signal and I am lost. I can not log in through ssh and can not switch to any console that I had hoped to be able to see on the external display since the boot process is displayed OK.

Any ideas how I can rescue my workshop laptop, any params to be given through the lilo prompt ?

Note that the system is up and running and I am able to reboot it trough CTRL+Alt+Del and get back to the LILO prompt, it's just that I have no display output.

Answer (score 0):

The forst step has been made : with the run level 3 as parameter to lilo I am now able to log into the system. Still, the question remains as to what to change in order to get the X screen again on the external monitor.

Comment: Starting with run level 3 allows to start x by hand and this is working, so the x configuration itself should be ok. One thing I noticed is that if I start normally ( so aiming for graphical UI at startup and run level 5 ) is that I can see the mouse on a black background and after that the external monitor goes off but also the background illumination of the laptop panel goes off, when I actually would expect some login window to appear.